# upload Multiple APK for mobile/table and TV in same app (Android). Google play developer console not working

Tags: android

I am trying upload Multiple APK for mobile/table and TV  in same app (Android). Google play developer console .
I have maintained different version code for mobile and TV app.
But when I try from tv to install app from google play . Only mobile app is displaying and not Tv App

Can anyone please correct me if I am missing anything.
Below is the Manifest configuration for TV app .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.qorva.klikr">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application
        android:name=".app.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:banner="@drawable/banner"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         </application>
</manifest>
```